# Upload multiple files in a directory and all subdirectories through API

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, grpc

What is the best practice to upload multiple files in a directory and all its subdirectories using an API of any kind (Web, REST, GRPC, etc.) and maintaining the directory structure?
PHP would be the preferred language used.

Comment: 1. do u mean your client side is also running PHP ? 2. why not simply use FTP/sFTP ?

Comment: 1. The client can be in any customer language, the server side is in PHP 2. I need to have a single request that send the files and informations